# Обработка запроса на сервере в потоках. Worker Threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, многопоточность

Хочу переписать SSR на сервере, что бы сам рендеринг проходил в отдельном потоке и не блокировал остальные запросы на сервер.

Не могу понять как мне дожидаться выполнения запроса , т.е рендеринг в потоке и только затем отдавать результат в теле запроса клиенту